# Calculating elapsed time for a message to receive a response (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the elapsed Time (in secs) until the first message received a response.

That is for a given order_id I would like to select

- Min(message_sent_time),
- from_id,
- to_id

and the elapsed time until to_id has responded, which in this case should be when to_id becomes from_id

-> please see

[image: Table structure]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post an example of the expected result? Especially the calculation of the elapsed time is unclear for me.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply.  

I would like to get the following columns. 

Order_id
Min(Message_sent_time)
Elapsed time in seconds (i.e how long did from_id wait to get an answer from to_id)

Comment: Ok, so for Elapsed time I take the minimal `Messaga_sent_time` where `To_id` = `Customer_Id` and subtract the minimal  `Message_sent_time` where `From_id` = `Customer_Id` (all for the same `Order_Id`)? Is it this what you want?

Comment: Exactly! It is all for the same order_id. Do you know how I could write this in a subquery to get the elapsed time? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it is only 'speudo code' I have actually no mysql pressent and don't know your tables name:

```
SELECT Min(a.message_sent_time), a.from_id, a.to_id,Min(b.message_sent_time) - Min(a.message_sent_time) elapsed_time
 FROM your_table a LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table B ON a.order_id = b.order_id and a.to_id = b.from_id
 GROUP BY a.order_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I need a Join, as there isn't a second table.

Comment: In my statement the table `your_table` is used twice. That's why I use table aliases `a` and `b` in the statement. Replace `your_table`  both with the name of your table.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept my answer, so everybody can see you are no longer searching for another answer. And it is like "Thank you" (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)